# How can I remove percent encoded slashes using .htaccess rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to "catch" incoming URLs that enter my server with extra "%252F" characters in the URL (due to some historical reasons) and redirect them (301) to the same url without these characters. For example:
incoming url: www.sample.com/content/%252F/foo
after .htaccess rule: www.sample.com/content/foo

I have to be able to catch several instances of these characters in the url (in the same place), like : www.sample.com/content/%252F/%252F/%252F/foo and remove them all.

Which .htaccess RewriteRule should I use?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to change "Unicode" to "percent encoded" - I think this is what you mean to say? If I'm wrong, feel free to roll back the change.

Comment: this might worth for try `AllowEncodedSlashes On` - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK RewriteRule must know the precise format of the incoming request URL. Therefore, having an arbitrary number of %252F strings in there isn't supported.

What you can do though is have a custom 404 page that parses the request URL for %252F. The custom 404 page would follow the following logic:

```
Search the request URL for %252F
  If found, replace it with a / (or nothing, up to you) and return a 301 header
    and an appropriate error page.
  Else return a 404 header and appropriate error page.
```

That should give you the effect you want.
Don't worry about the extra slashes, apache ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (/.*?)?((/%2F)+)(.*) $1$4 [redirect=301,last]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/%2F(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

but there is a drawback, it does multiple redirects ( 1 for each group of %252F )