# .htaccess to remove percent-encoded part of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534227/how-can-i-remove-percent-encoded-slashes-using-htaccess-rule) except for I would like to be able to cut off the percent-encoded part of the URL. E.g. change

```
http://www.example.com/filename.html%20
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/filename.html
```

I used to do simple 301 redirects, but they don't seem to work with percents:

> <strike>Redirect 301 /filename.html%20 http://www.example.com/filename.html</strike>

Thus it'd had to be a .htaccess rule. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked out for me after all:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)%.* http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Thank you @KingKongFrog for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^%]+)\%
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I've got to so far myself.. It still doesn't work, it just removes the percent sign, but leaves the rest: `http://www.example.com/filename.html20`

Comment: New answer...try the above.

Comment: it still not working. Looks like it cant recognize the THE_REQUEST var?